# Uploaded build on TestFlight but not seeing any builds

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, xcode8, testflight

I have uploaded my build(with a new version as 0.3.6) on TestFlight using Xcode 8.2, and it has shown me a "Upload success" message. But on iTunes Connect under TestFlight tab i am not able to see any builds and it shows as shown in below image with "No Builds". If i try to upload it again that it is giving error message as "Redundant binary Upload". Am i missing any thing?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced same issue many times.

But succeeded the second time I tried by incrementing the build number for the same app version.
[image]

Also check the Bundle identifier, provisioning profile, etc. on safer side.

If it still not work, [Application Loader](https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/204456258-iOS-Uploading-Builds-Using-Application-Loader) can also support. [Here is how to use it.](https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/204456258-iOS-Uploading-Builds-Using-Application-Loader)

Also complete the Export Compliance certificate I was able to see the app in TestFlight. There is a high chance that your app may also need to complete it.

In iTunesconnect, go to TestFlight (Tab) > iOS (Sidemenu) > iOS Builds select the latest build and complete the Export Compliance.

Comment: I'm uploading build with Application Loader (Version 3.7, tried 3.0 as well). Getting email fro apple "The following build has completed processing. You can now use this build for TestFlight testing or submit it to the App Store." App shows in Activity tab but not in Testflight tab. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I tried this but still no luck. i still can see "No builds" under "Builds" tab. Even i am not getting any warning or error email.